# WooCommerce Smart Coupons override "available coupons" position

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, overriding

I am using Wordpress 4.6 with WooCommerce 2.6.4 and Smart Coupon 3.1.2 plugin.
I would like to move the "available coupons" section from the top of my checkout page to the bottom.

In the plugin file I've detected this structure and the action that I need to change.

I need to change it to 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form' but I can't get my head around on how to override it from the functions.php file.

I've already tried directly from the plugin to change it and it works like I would but we all know that it's a wrong approach to edit a plugin's behaviour.

Any help and documentation would be really helpful.

```
class WC_Smart_Coupons {

  ...

   public function __construct() {

    ...

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array(  $this, 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );

    ...

   }
}

...

function initialize_smart_coupons() {
    $GLOBALS['woocommerce_smart_coupon'] = new WC_Smart_Coupons();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'initialize_smart_coupons' );
```

Comment: This is what i've done so far by checking documentations but it's not working :
`function remove_plugin_actions(){
        global $WC_Smart_Coupons;
    
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array(   $WC_Smart_Coupons, 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','remove_plugin_actions');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I had similar problem today. You can do following to move that section to different place.

To remove:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array(  $GLOBALS['woocommerce_smart_coupon'], 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );
```

To add:

```
add_action( 'any_action', array(  $GLOBALS['woocommerce_smart_coupon'], 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );
```

Comment: Brilliant, Yalamber! I tried to use traditional docs as ref but couldn't make it work. Your solution instead WORKS! Thank you, you saved a plugin update (and maybe more, I'll try this method even on others). :)

Comment: Glad it helped you as well. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea why this won't work in WooCommerce Smart Coupons v 4.7.0? Strange thing is that even if I edit /plugins/woocommerce-smart-coupons/includes/class-sc-display-coupons.php and delete or modify all the actions in the Constructor it still appears on the checkout?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution doesn't work for the Smart Coupons version I use (4.12.2).

To change the "available coupons" position use the following instead:

```
$obj_inst = WC_SC_Display_Coupons::get_instance();
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array(  $obj_inst, 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', array(  $obj_inst, 'show_available_coupons_before_checkout_form' ), 11 );
```

A nifty visual list of woocommerce checkout page hooks can be found [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/).